# Access Spotfire object by SpotfireControl Id

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I know the `SpotfireControl Id` value of an object and I want to access it via an Ironpython script. I looked at the API, but failed to find a method that can do it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you just reference it by name `Document.Data.Properties.GetProperty(DataPropertyClass.Document, "PropertyName")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a little, please? For example, if I had an object e.g. with `SpotfireControl id="1811b398bb824a64a7e3c7d6cb0d4689"`, then how would I get it? `Document.Data.Properties.GetProperty(DataPropertyClass.Docum‌​ent, "1811b398bb824a64a7e3c7d6cb0d4689")` seems to fail (somehow I get an unexpected token error)

Comment: It's what ever you named that ID when you created it. Is it a property control or an action item or a calculated value or...?

Comment: `<TD><SpotfireControl id="1811b398bb824a64a7e3c7d6cb0d4689" /></TD>` this is a copy of a small part of the HtmlContent of a HtmlTextArea object, which contains several objects inside, one of them having the said `SpotfireControl id` value

Comment: If you look on the right you can see the name of that control.

Comment: You mean if I hit right click -> Edit Html? That is indeed correct, but I am not doing that. I am writing an Ironpython script that is supposed to do the "looking" for me. The best I can do so far is access the HtmlContent as a string

Answer (score 2):

```
Right Click > Edit HTML
```

Then, on the right hand side, slick on the names you see. It will highlight the name of the `SpotfireControl` ID associated with it.

This is the name you need to use in

```
Document.Data.Properties.GetProperty(DataPropertyClass.Docum‌​ent, "PropertyName")
```

Comment: I am not so sure if this is correct. I tried both the name in the right and the actual `SpotfireControl id` and they both raise a `KeyError`, with the message "The property named (...) could not be found."
P.S. For completeness purposes, edit your answer to also include `from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass`

Comment: What kind of control is it?

Comment: It is not one file or one sheet or one text area and I do not have any control over it. It could be anything. This time there is one input and one output field, but in general it could be anything.